# beta 2.8 screen capture

Tags: interface, shortcut

How to make a **screen capture video** in 2.8 beta? In 2.79 the **screen capture** shortcut was Alt-F3. Is there an alternative way in 2.8 beta? (The *screencast* is in the Window pulldown and has, as far as I can tell, no shortcut.)

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.8x, every menu item that doesn't have a shortcut can be assigned one very easily:

1. right click on the menu item, then
2. either select

   - *Add to Quick Favorites*: your quick favorites will be available under the<kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut for quick selection
   - *Assign Shortcut*: you can now assign a custom unique shortcut.

I think the developers have made sure to leave <kbd>F4</kbd> to <kbd>F10</kbd> unassigned ("minimal keymap" philosophy) so that you can use these keys as custom hotkeys.

Comment: Thx for the answer. But my issue is foremost the screen capture possibility. I edited my question to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You mean a **video** screen capture as opposed to a **still** screen capture?

Comment: Correct. In the manual it is called screen capture (video) as opposed to screen cast (still).

Comment: Oh sorry then. I thought you could find your functionality and all you were missing was the shortcut. I'm not sure I can help with this as I use external applications for screencasts (mostly for [answer to posts](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers))